# Retrieving forecast data from OpenWeatherMap in FIWARE ORION

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, openweathermap

I am trying to get weather forecasts data from OpenWeatherMap and integrate them in Orion by performing a registeration request.

I was able to register and get the API key from OpenWeatherMap, however, the latter returns a JSON file with all the data inside, which is not supported by ORION.

I have followed the step by step tutorial https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/context-providers/index.html#context-provider-ngsi-proxy where they have acquired the data from OpenWeatherMap using NGSI proxy, an API key is required to be indicated in the docker-compose file as an environment variable, however, the data acquired is the "current data" and not forecast and also specific to Berlin.

I have tried to access the files inside the container "fiware/tutorials.context-provider" and try to modify and match the parameters to my needs but I feel like I am taking a long blocked path.

I don't think that's even considered as good practice but I have run out of ideas :(

Can anyone suggest how I could bring the forecast data to Orion and register it as a context provider?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you aim to implement a context provider, able to speak NGSI with Orion.
OpenWeatherMap surely doesn't implement NGSI ...

If you have the data from OpenWeatherMap, as a JSON string, perhaps you should parse the JSON and create your entities using some select key-values from the parsed OpenWeatherMap? Save the entity (entities) locally and then register those keys in Orion.

Alternatively (easier but I wouldn't recommend it), create local entities with the entire OpenWeatherMap data as the value of an attribute of the entity:

{
  "id": "id-from-OpenWeatherMap",
  "type": "OpenWeatherMap",
  "weatherData": {
    "value": 
    ...
  }
  ...
}

Then you register id/weatherData in Orion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I believe the first solution you proposed is kind of related to this <https://ngsi-js-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ngsi/docs/JSONParser/#json-parser-functions> I am wondering if I would still be able to use Orion "registration" mechanism and register "something" as a context provider after I send the parsed entity to Orion or i will only be able to post updated entities to Orion without requiring to make any registrations.

Comment: About that doc ... unfortunate name they have chosen. If I understand it correctly it's a JSON builder, not a parser. So no, what you need is the reverse - you need to parse a JSON string and convert it to something you can use inside your program. If you use Javascript I think you can simply use the JSON string as an object (not an expert ...).

And yes, you can register your entity in orion. Your program needs to be prepared to deal with forwarded requests - updates and queries. See http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable, even though context providers aren't too explained

Comment: This page in Orion manual provides information about context providers and fowarding: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/context_providers/index.html